# Forms and DataGridviews interaction in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have one form on which there is one gridview containing 4 columns. Column1 is LinkColumn having a link Text in each cell of this column oon each row. When i will click on this link it will return me values other 3 columns of that row.

**My Code**

```
{
//filling gridview 
grdOne.datasource=DT_values;
}
```

My problem is when i can get those values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void grdOne_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                //Column0 will be that column on which you will click
                //Suppose column having string values 
                string Column1 = grdOne["Column1", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                string Column2  = grdOne["Column2", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                string Column3  = grdOne["Column3", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
                //here you got all these values 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**So far i Understand
Use Event of `CellContent` Click and get those values one by one by passing ref on Columns.**

Comment: Can you give me code Sample @AHMAD SUMRAIZ

Comment: Sure! Just wait 2 minutes @user1837554